# Cause for Drupal node.Auto_increment field jump to the hundred millions (from half a million)?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-6

The nid field on my Drupal node table jumped from from 254,107 to 500,220,117. What could have caused that? I haven't messed up with the Auto_increment field.

I see very little leeway in the drupal_write_record and node_save function calls for any kind human errors that could cause this nid jump, node_save what accepts as an argument is a node object.

Could a badly built node object cause a jump in the Auto_increment field? i.e. that for some sort of weird bug the code switches the nid field with something else before passing it to node_save? If this were true, the bug would be in the code preceding the node_save, but it could also be inside a rougue [hook_invoke_nodeapi](http://api.drupal.org/api/search/6/hook_invoke_nodeapi), since node_save() calls this snippet at the beginning of the function:

```
// Let modules modify the node before it is saved to the database.
node_invoke_nodeapi($node, 'presave');
```

How would you go about setting a test for detecting this?

I will probably set up an exotic conditional breakpoint (or a couple of them) within node_save(), and particularly on the last line of [db_query()](http://api.drupal.org/api/search/6/db_query). In db_query() the breakpoint will most likely contain a regular expression. Then I could set some sort of automated test that saves all kinds of node types into the database (thinking about the devel module) and see if something appears. If I find anything I will answer myself the question, unless someone else had a similar experience in the past and answers first.

Comment: Poorly-written module? Hard to say with such little information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, we can't know without more information. What Drupal uses for it's sequencing depends on the version you are using. See [this](http://drupal.org/node/213091) for more info.